# Nested struct initialization with structs

Tags: c, struct

maybe this is a duplicate but I can't find a proper solution for this problem... and I'm sort of being new to C development, and my problem is that I don't know how to initialized a nested struct, take a look for more info...
So the thing is the following:

```
// another_struct.h
struct AnotherStruct {
    void (*some_function)();
}
extern struct AnotherStruct AnotherStruct;

// yet_another_struct.h
struct YetAnotherStruct {
    void (*some_function)();
}
extern struct YetAnotherStruct YetAnotherStruct;

// my_struct.h
struct MyStruct1 {
    struct AnotherStruct another;
    struct YetAnotherStruct and_yet;
}
extern struct MyStruct1 MyStruct1;
```

In their respective .C file:

```
struct AnotherStruct AnotherStruct = {
    .some_function = blabla
};

struct YetAnotherStruct YetAnotherStruct = {
    .some_function = blablabla
};

// I want the initialization of MyStruct1 to have the struct pointing to the structs
struct MyStruct1 MyStruct1 = { /* ?? */ };

/* I was thinking something like this */
struct MyStruct1 MyStruct1 = {
    .another = AnotherStruct,
    .and_yet = YetAnotherStruct
};
```

But the compiler complains xD
So my ultimate goal is to be able access the child structures as:

```
MyStruct1.another.some_function();
```

Thanks a lot and sorry if this question is duplicate or is way to noob :)

Comment: What is the complain? THe way you want to use these structs, use pointers.

Comment: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you construct them like this (No pointer usage):

```
/* I was thinking something like this */
struct MyStruct1 MyStruct1 = {
    .another = { //.another is your struct, just do construct like normal
        .some_function = blabla
    },
    .and_yet = { //The same here.
        .some_function = blablabla
    }
};
```

Usage in your code is:

```
//Call function
MyStruct1.another.some_function();
```

---

Using pointers:

```
// my_struct.h, add pointers
struct MyStruct1 {
    struct AnotherStruct *another; //Added pointers
    struct YetAnotherStruct *and_yet; //Here too
}
```

and then use in your .c

```
struct AnotherStruct AnotherStruct = {
    .some_function = blabla
};
struct YetAnotherStruct YetAnotherStruct = {
    .some_function = blablabla
};

/* I was thinking something like this */
struct MyStruct1 MyStruct1 = {
    .another = &AnotherStruct, //Added & for address
    .and_yet = &YetAnotherStruct //Added & for address
};
```

And later access to your values like:

```
//Call your function now
MyStruct1.another->some_function();
```

Comment: Yea, I mean this solves it but was wondering if there's a way of doing it the other way :)

Comment: so you mean defining the MyStruct as having them with pointers? AnotherStruct* another?

Comment: yea, hmmm... MyStruct1.another->some_function() is not exactly what I was looking for but does the trick; I heard something about using union, what's your thinking about it?

Comment: @ArnulfoSolisRamirez There is no other way than these 2 options for initializing at a time. What is wrong with pointers?

Comment: nothing :) just was curious about the union thinggy, will use the pointer way thanks a million!

Answer (score -1):

@tilz0R not enough rep to comment. A little modification to your answer.

```c
typedef struct {
  int a_val;
} A;

typedef struct {
  float b_val;
} B;

typedef struct {
  A *a;
  B *b;
} C;

C c = {
  .a = &(A){ .a_val = 1 },
  .b = &(B){ .b_val = 1. },
};
```

As for union thingie, probably it is about Microsoft extension syntax

```c
typedef struct {
  A;
  B;
} C;

C c;

c.a_val = 1; // valid
```

Unfortunately this one is a non standard extension, moreover it is doomed to never become one since this was a committee decision to maintain compatibility with C++.

---

Per @Lundin comment. The following code is indeed possible in modern C:

```c
typedef struct {
  struct {
    int a_val;
  };
  struct {
    float b_val;
  };
} C;

C c;

c.a_val = 1;
```

However this brings little to no benefit (apart from organizing your code) in case of embedding structures into structures. It is pretty cool than it comes to unions though:

```c
typedef struct {
  enum {
    TA,
    TB
  } _;
  union {
    struct {
      int a;
    };
    struct {
      float b;
    };
  };
} C;

C c = { ._ = TA, .a = 1 };
```

---

Used compile line:

```
gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

Comment: Simply don't name the structs and you can use their members like in your example: `c.a_val`. Anonymous structs were added with C11.

Comment: @tgregory How is first part of answer correcting my answer? You are also adding pointers, just like I did them which is not what OP wants.

Comment: @tilz0R not a correction, rather a slight modification in the initialization section (part about how to initialize all at once).

Comment: @tgregory The question is very stupid at all and I don't know what is wrong that he don't want to use one big structure at init, but anyway, he got the possible options :)

Comment: @tilz0R The question itself is somewhat natural for a person coming from a higher level languages, which are more syntax sugar rich and forgiving. C may be tricky at first until you figure the way to write an idiomatic code. You are correct though, all the options are given ;)